# Why is adding a dependency with Intellij in the Maven Artifact search not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to set up Spring boot in my project. I am using the `@Repository` annotation and searching for it using the add dependency pop up in intellij - it is under the `org.springframework.stereotype` class in release 5.2.8. I click *Add* as this is the dependency I need and nothing happens.

How do I resolve this issue? Another thing I noticed in my `pom.xml` file the only Spring boot starter parent version I can add is `2.3.2` and not later versions.

See my `pom.xml` file below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://ma––ven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-project-test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Looking at previous questions I deleted the `.m2` directory and will reinstall maven with *brew* - I'm using Mac OS. I added this snippet directly from the Spring boot example page and it's not resolving the release version. It only resolves version `2.3.2`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I've also used Spring Initalizer to use version `2.3.4` and I open this project directly in intellij - I am getting the same problem in that it cannot find `2.3.4` spring-boot-starter-parent release.

Comment: Are you trying to use @Repository and IntelliJ won't recognize it?

Comment: Yes. I've detailed what's happening in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ comes with a bundled maven, so make sure you use the one you actually want(between the installed one and the bundled one) by configuring the Maven settings in IntelliJ. Probably you are using the bundled one by default, so you have to hit the reload button on the maven tab(upper right).

Comment: I'm updating the indexed maven repo as I've noticed it's never been updated and is using my local one in .m2 - it should be using the online version from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 - is this what you mean?

Comment: No, in IntelliJ -> Preferences you have a Maven section in which you specify which Maven Home Directory to use, which local repository and so on.

Comment: Thank you, it worked by going to preferences/maven/importing and unchecking "exclude build directory" which was checked for some reason